# Import Error: No module named shapely.wkb

Tags: geojson, python-2.6, postgis-1.5

OpenERP GeoEngine

I have installed **OpenERP 6.1** version, works fine. When I'm trying to add **CamptoCamp GeoEngine Modules with OpenERP** getting below find error:

**Installation Prerequisites:**

```
OpenERP 6.1,CamptoCamp GeoEngine modules(sales,partner) ,Python 2.6,Shapley 1.2.18,Geojson 1.0.1,   POSTGIS 1.5
```

When starting server in service it throws below error:

```
12:43:00,283 1904 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 6.1-20130918-233418

12:43:00,283 1904 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: E:\OpenERP 6.1-20130918-233418\Server\server\openerp\addons

12:43:00,283 1904 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost

12:43:00,283 1904 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432

12:43:00,283 1904 INFO ? openerp: database user: openpg

12:43:00,315 1904 INFO ? openerp.service.netrpc_server: starting NET-RPC service on 0.0.0.0:8070

12:43:00,315 1904 INFO ? openerp.netsvc: Starting 1 services

12:43:00,361 1904 INFO ? openerp.wsgi.core: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069 12:43:00,440 1904 INFO ? openerp.addons.web: embedded mode

12:43:00,642 1904 CRITICAL ? **openerp.modules.module: Couldn't load module web**

12:43:00,642 1904 CRITICAL ? **openerp.modules.module: No module named shapely.wkb**

12:43:00,642 1904 ERROR ? openerp: Failed to load server-wide module `web`.
The `web` module is provided by the addons found in the `openerp-web` project.
Maybe you forgot to add those addons in your addons_path configuration.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "openerp-server", line 252, in <module>

  File "E:\OpenERP 6.1\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\module.py", line 419, in load_openerp_module

  File "E:\OpenERP 6.1\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\__init__.py", line 29, in wsgi_postload

  File "E:\OpenERP 6.1\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\common\http.py", line 453, in __init__

  File "E:\OpenERP 6.1\Server\server\openerp\addons\web\common\http.py", line 523, in _load_addons

  File "E:\OpenERP 6.1\Server\server\.\openerp\modules\module.py", line 139, in load_module

  File "E:\OpenERP 6.1\Server\server\openerp\addons\base_geoengine\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>

  File "E:\OpenERP 6.1Server\server\openerp\addons\base_geoengine\geo_model.py", line 11, in <module>

  File "E:\OpenERP 6.1\Server\server\openerp\addons\base_geoengine\geo_field.py", line 9, in <module>

**ImportError: No module named shapely.wkb**

2013-09-24 12:43:00,642 1904 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP server is running, waiting for connections...
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! It would be really helpful if you could add some context to your problem. What were you trying to accomplish? What have you tried in order to solve your problem? Etc..

Answer (score 3):

Simple step for this problem

```
sudo apt-get install python-shapely
```

it will work

Answer (score 2):

I don't know ERP but the error indicates that the Python module [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) is not installed:

[image]

Comment: [Download Shapely for Windows here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely)

Comment: Already Installed shapley by using as you refered ,it installed in location C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\shapely..

Comment: Open ERP use the same Python ?

Comment: I hope So ..Geoengine camptocamp is based on OpenERP 6.1, they didn't port yet the module for 7.0 version